# FTP Release in Installshield doesn't work

Tags: ftp, installshield

I'm using FTP Release feature provided in Installshield 2011.
My project complies and deploys via FTP properly if I compile it on my dev box.

When building the solution via teambuild, it doesn't ftp the file to the ftp server. It doesn't throw up any errors either.

In the build log, it says:
Copy Files to Drop Location 00:00

I can ftp to the ftp server manually from the TFS server without problem. Even if I disable the windows firewall, it still fails.

There are no errors in the windows event log either.

**Dev box**:
Windows 7 x64 
Visual Studio 2010
Installshield 2011
using cmd line msbuild to build the solution deploys the file via FTP.

**Server**:
Windows 2008 R2 x64
TFS 2010
Installshileld Standalone Build
Windows Firewall Disabled.
using cmd line msbuild builds the solution but does not deploy the file via ftp and displays no errors.
No events in the event log, or in the firewall log.

Watching the build happen, it doesn't even appear as if Installshield is trying to FTP the file. It doesn't pause or hang like its trying to establish a connection at all.

Any Ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

People still use that feature? :-)   FTP is an unsecure protocol.

Do you have a firewall installed on your build machine?  I'm wondering if the service account you are using is restricted from opening the connnection.

Comment: Company policy is to ftp the releases on the ftp server, so cannot compromise there. And yeah, Windows firewall is disabled and it doesn't seem to hang or pause like it's trying to connect to the ftp server.

Comment: Can you copy it to a \\unc\path that is exposed externally as an FTP site?  Or don't use distribute to ftp via instalshield write a tfs msbuild task to do it instead.  If there is an FTP site that you do releases to and you can write to it as part of your build via ftp then I'd consider that a big security whole in your IT infrastructure.

Comment: Ftp server is just for internal purpose and customers do not have access to it, they download the software from a webserver. What other options do you propose to save a file on a remote file server, considering security and using TFS ofcourse.